# Easier way to search through large files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple log sniffer that will search logs for specific errors that are indicative of issues with the software I support. It allows the user to specify the path to the log and specify how many days back they'd like to search.

If users have log roll over turned off, the log files can sometimes get quite large. Currently I'm doing the following (though not done with it yet):

```
File.open(@log_file, "r") do |file_handle|
    file_handle.each do |line|
        if line.match(/\d+++-\d+-\d+/)
          etc...
```

The line.match obviously looks for the date format we use in the logs, and the rest of the logic will be below. However, is there a better way to search through the file without .each_line? If not, I'm totally fine with that. I just wanted to make sure I'm using the best resources available to me.

Thanks

Comment: Better in what sense -- speed, code simplicity, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `fgrep` as a standalone or called from `system('fgrep ...')` may be faster solution
- `file.readlines` might be better in speed, but it's a time-space tradeoff
- look at [this](http://smyck.net/2011/02/12/parsing-large-logfiles-with-ruby/) little research - last approaches seem to be rather fast.

Comment: +1 for `fgrep`. I'd go with any solution using `grep/`fgrep`/`egrep` as they're going to run extremely fast because that's their purpose in life, searching text files for lines of text.

Answer (score 4):

If your log file is sorted by date, then you can avoid having search through the entire file by doing a binary search. In this case you'd:

1. Open the file like you are doing
2. Use [lineo=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-lineno-3D) to fast forward to the middle of the file.
3. Check if the date on the beging of the line is higher or lower than the date you are looking for.
4. Continue splitting the file in halves until you find what you need.

I do however think your file needs to be *very* large for the above to make sense.

**Edit**

Here is some code which shows the basic idea. It find a line containing search date, not the first. This can be fixed either by more binary searches or by doing an linear search from the last midpoint, which did not contain date. There also isn't a termination condition in case the date is not in the file. These small additions, are left as an exercise to the reader :-)

```
require 'date'

def bin_fsearch(search_date, file)
  f = File.open file

  search = {min: 0, max: f.size}

  while true
    # go to file midpoint
    f.seek (search[:max] + search[:min]) / 2

    # read in until EOL
    f.gets

    # record the actual mid-point we are using
    pos = f.pos

    # read in next line
    line = f.gets

    # get date from line
    line_date = Date.parse(line)

    if line_date < search_date
      search[:min] = f.pos
    elsif line_date > search_date
      search[:max] = pos
    else
      f.seek pos
      return
    end
  end
end

bin_fsearch(Date.new(2013, 5, 4), '/var/log/system.log')
```

Comment: Please show some code demonstrating how you're going to jump to the middle of a file being read line-by-line with variable length lines. While this sounds easy to describe, I suspect the code won't be that easy, especially if you're hoping for speed.

Comment: @theTinMan It's pretty easy to aline to line boundaries after random access.  Just `seek` to a point and do a `gets` to skip the partial line you landed on.  The next gets is a whole line.

Comment: @dbenhur, it's not simply a case of doing `gets` to clean up a partial line. The remnant of the string needs to be appended to the last line that was read from the previous block to test for the pattern being searching for, because a word that was split might have been a match. A partial line from the previous block could be sensed and then prepended to the front of the new block, but, either way, there's additional logic required, slowing the overall code and eating into any benefit of block reads. Line IO is buffered so it is very fast, plus it's very simple to implement.

Comment: @theTinMan sure it is, as long as when you take the next line in one of the cases, you make sure to set the seek posistion to the "truncated" line in the other case. Like in the code above.

Comment: @theTinMan  It can be that simple if you degrade to a forward scan once your interval size is some small multiple of your max line size. The more fiddly problem is UTF-8 alignment actually.  On big files, no matter the expense of fiddling with buffers around the pivot. the time can be reduced from 10s of minutes to fractions of a second. Perhaps you have never worked in an environment where logs are accumulated at 10s of gigs per day? I have several services that generate > 100GB of logs/day. grep & awk can take an hour to extract a five minute window, while binary search takes seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some coding hints...

Instead of:

```
File.open(@log_file, "r") do |file_handle|
  file_handle.each do |line|
```

use:

```
File.foreach(@log_file) do |line|
  next unless line[/\A\d+++-\d+-\d+/]
```

`foreach` simplifies opening and looping over the file.

`next unless...` makes a tight loop skipping every line that does NOT start with your target string. The less you do before figuring out whether you have a good line, the faster your code will run.

Using an anchor at the start of your pattern, like `\A` gives the regex engine a major hint about where to look in the line, and allows it to bail out very quickly if the line doesn't match. Also, using `line[/\A\d+++-\d+-\d+/]` is a bit more concise.

Comment: Thanks for that. I come from the PHP world, and I'd never claim to be really good at that either, so seeing how people refactor in Ruby to make things better is always a bonus. I appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will search one time at a time & should be pretty fast & takes less memory.

```
File.open(file, 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    # do stuff here to line
  end
end
```

Another more faster option is to read the whole file into one array. it would be fast but will take LOT of memory.

```
File.readlines.each do |line|
  #do stuff with each line
end
```

Further, if you need fastest approach with least amount of memory try `grep` which is specifically tuned for searching through large files. so should be fast & memory responsive

```
`grep -e regex bigfile`.split(/\n/).each do |line|
  # ... (called on each matching line) ...
end
```

Comment: Reading the entire file into an an array isn't faster. Ruby still has to figure out where every line-ending is before it begins passing lines to the block, and the memory allocation for a big file can accidentally kill a machine if a file is unexpectedly big. On a big file that slows down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Faster than line-by-line is read the line by chunks:

```
File.open('file.txt') do |f|
  buff = f.read(10240)
  # ...
end
```

But you are using regexp to match dates, you might get incomplete lines. You will  have to deal with it in your logic.

Also, if performance is that important, consider write a really simple C extension.

Comment: Reading by chunks isn't that big of a difference in speed, and, with the hassle of having to rebuild split lines, it becomes a hassle. Also, chunks require splitting the lines, or writing different regex to track the start and end of each line. File IO, using `each`, `each_line` or `for_each` is surprisingly fast, and results in a lot simpler algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If the log file can get huge, and that is your concern, then maybe you can consider saving the errors in a database. Then, you will get faster response.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I just don't have control over that. We may end up using this on client systems, and they're not likely to allow me to mess with their dbms.

Comment: Getting the data into the database is typically the problem. If the loggers that generate the files are under the OPs control then it'd be easier to do. If they're not, then something will have to be written to read the logs and extract the lines of interest, parse them into fields, and insert the records into the database. It's all doable, but it isn't a simple fix either. It is good for the long run though, especially as the number of log files grow.

Comment: SQLite is also a database.